# Can anyone make their own Beis Din

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, money, beit-din-court, gezel-stealing

This morning I did Hafaros Nedarim, where a panel of 3 people from my shul became 'Dayanim' and were Matir my Nedarim. Considering these were just regular people from my shul, this gave me the question: What's stopping any group of 3 (or more) jews from getting together, and declaring themselves a Beis Din? They can then proceed to rule on monetary matters and declare people's property Hefker, or transfer people's money in to a 3rd party who has agreed to share it with them. If anyone can be part of a Beis Din in shul, why can't they do this in other cases as well?

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17980/which-beis-din-can-declare-items-hefker?rq=1) shows opinions on which Beis Din can make things Hefker, and there are opinions that hold even a Beis Din of Hedyotos can make items Hefker!

Comment: @DoubleAA, That question preludes to mine. It explains who is eligible to serve on a Beis Din, and says that there are even opinions that a Beis Din of Hedyotos can make things Hefker. Therefore, I have my question of what will practically be able to stop people from making their own Beis Din to steal.